# Disabling internet connections while keeping one web service online

Tags: networking, routing, lan, domain, gateway

I know similiar questions were asked, but my problem has a little twist. I'm new at IT administration, but my supervisor gave me a task to complete:
I have to disable web browsing on one of the workstations in the domain, but I have to do it so that one of the web services placed on a special ip address and port is available. It should be done locally as changing anything in the company's firewall is out of question and changing AD policies is a last resort. Deleting the default gateway is not an option, as it disables all connections. The workstation is connected via DHCP and has to stay this way. I tried adding a rule to PCs firewall via netsh command but it didn't change anything. Adding all forbidden websites to hosts file is too time-consuming. The PC runs Win7 pro 64bit.

tl;dr

users shouldn't be able to browse the internet, but they have to be able to access a service placed on an IP:specific_port.

Comment: Do users of the computer in question have admin privileges? Can you install software on the computer?

Comment: Users don't have admin privelages, I do (either via UAC or loging on account with admin privelages)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Win 7 firewall options and neither do you indicate whether installing a 3rd party firewall would be a feasible solution, but the only way to achieve this task I can think of would be to configure the firewall of the computer in question to suppress any unwanted outgoing traffic.

Answer (score 2):

Letting 192.168.0.1 be your gateway, and 1.2.3.4 the whitelisted host,
define a static route for 1.2.3.4 that uses 192.168.0.1,
and define 192.168.0.253 to be the default router
(where 192.168.0.253 either does not exist,
or is a plain host that doesn't do IP forwarding). 
This will not lock users down to a single port,
but (hopefully) it will stop them from getting to any other server.

Comment: That's definitely something I'd like to try, but will it allow to contact the required app via web browser?

Comment: Well, that is the question I was trying to answer.  Do you have some reason for questioning whether it will work?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all your answers and suggestions. During my experiments it turned out that global solution has to be found (due to other workstations accessing the internet), so my question is no longer relevant. G-Man's solution was a close call, but like I mentioned - now I have to set up global blockade for the production site. It will be done with a linux virtual machine that will act as a router/gateway.